# Integrate of the product measure on $R^2$

Tags: measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I have to prove this property that seems very intuitive:

Let $µ$ and $ν$ be finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$ and $µ\timesν$ their product measure on $\mathbb{R^2}$. Prove:

$\int_\mathbb{R^2} (x^2+y^2)dµ \timesν(x,y) <∞$ if and only if $\int_\mathbb{R} x^2dµ(x) <∞$ and $\int_\mathbb{R} y^2dν(y) <∞$.

Sorry for the bad writting, x means the product measure.

Comment: This is basically linearity of the integral and Tonelli...

Comment: \times gives $\times$

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the following equlities:
$$\int_\mathbb{R^2} (x^2+y^2)dµ(x) \times d ν(y)=
\int_\mathbb{R^2} (x^2 \times 1)dµ(x) \times d ν(y)+\int_\mathbb{R^2}(1\times  y^2)dµ(x) \times d ν(y)$$
$$=\int_\mathbb{R} x^2dµ(x) \int_\mathbb{R}dv (y) +\int_\mathbb{R} d µ(x)\int_\mathbb{R} y^2dv(y)=
$$
$$=\int_\mathbb{R} x^2dµ(x) \times v(\mathbb{R})+µ(\mathbb{R}) \times \int_\mathbb{R} y^2dv(y)
$$